# How to add a variable with a text box to edit it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add a variable called "tokeninput". I want add a text box to edit this variable.

I was searching for few hours now and didn't find a result.

```
<script src="https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js"></script>
 <script>

window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {
const token = '`enter token here`';
const player = new Spotify.Player({
  name: 'Speaker of some sort',
  getOAuthToken: cb => { cb(token); }

 });

</script>
```

So the expected to be is when I would put a token found on a page and inputed It the player would work.

Thanks in advance
EDIT: Thanks to everyone who helped. The finall script worked with the help from the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want to have a textbox in html to adjust the token than call that Spotify.player function?

```
<html>
 <body> 
   <input type="text" id="token" />
   <script>
      function updateToken(){
           var token = document.getElementById("token");
           // Do whatever with the token here
       }
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This can also be extracted out to it's own js file if that's where all the other spotify api logic is.

Comment: Yes i am trying to do this but the code you provided (raw and on other run edited by me didn't work). I don't know if this is my error becouse if i add the token manualy in the code the spotify  player works without a problem. But this metod doesn't work. If you could edit the code provided with the technique for editing text like the code you provided I would be greatfull. EDIT: no I don't mean to edit Spotify.player  but the part of the code  here:                             const token = '`enter token here`';

Comment: @modman276 Sorry try adding body tags and putting the input and script tags inside it.

Comment: @modman276 really all you should need is `var token = document.getElementById("token");` and the input tag on the html side.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the element dynamically using JS like,

```js
var input = document.createElement('input'); 
input.type = "text"; 
input.placeholder = "enter token here";
document.body.appendChild(input); 
input.addEventListener("blur", function(e){
// add your code to use token here.
  alert("token is "+ input.value);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code:

```
<script src="https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js"></script>
<script>

window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {
const prompt = '`enter token here`';
const token = $('#idOfTokenInput'); // OR document.querySelector('idorClassofInputelement')
const player = new Spotify.Player({
  name: 'Speaker of some sort',
  getOAuthToken: cb => { cb(token); }

 });
 // To update the Token with input change
 $('#idOfTokenInput').keydown(function(event) { 
    token = $('#idOfTokenInput').value;
 }); 

</script>
```